# Android AvoidXferMode Drawing Path Bug?

Tags: android, colors, path, paint, mode

I am using AvoidXferMode to draw Paths only above the black color, but there is a problem, the border of the paths get colored black and it gets all messed up..

I will show you the photos to better understanding

This is the image before draw.. just a black square..
[image: Before Drawing]

This is the starting of the draw, using Path.
[image: Starting the draw..]

And then finnally when I get the entire square drawned using various Paths, it gets this aspect
[image: After the draw]

Does anyone knows how to fix this? I don't want to see black lines around the several Paths..

This might be a bug of AvoidXferMode?

This is my paint object:

```
    Xfermode mode = new AvoidXfermode(Color.BLACK, 0, AvoidXfermode.Mode.TARGET);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(stroke);
    mPaint.setXfermode(mode);
```

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a test, try setting anti-aliasing to false. You might be seeing artifacts where the edges of your yellow strokes were dithered over the black background.

Comment: Oh my godness! It worked so well! Thanks alot mate! Really appreciated

Comment: Np; sometimes all it takes is another set of eyes.